# ASP.Net MVC: Map route according to parameter value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, wizard, maproute

I'm trying to create a wizard-like workflow on a site, and I have a model for each one of the steps.

I have the following action methods:

```
public ActionResult Create();
public ActionResult Create01(Model01 m);
public ActionResult Create02(Model02 m);
public ActionResult Create03(Model03 m);
```

And I want the user to see the address as

```
/Element/Create
/Element/Create?Step=1
/Element/Create?Step=2
/Element/Create?Step=3
```

All the model classes inherit from a BaseModel that has a Step property.
The action methods that have the parameters have the correct AcceptVerbs constraint.

I tried naming all the methods Create, but that resulted in a AmbiguousMatchException.

What I want to do now is to create a custom route for each one of the actions, but I can't figure out how to do it.
This is what I tried:

```
     routes.MapRoute(
        "ElementsCreation", 
        "Element/Create",
        new{controller="Element", action="Create01"},
        new{Step="1"}
        );
```

But this doesn't work.

Any help (on the correct MapRoute call or maybe a different approach) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a different approach.

Instead of adding a new Route Map, I created a new Action Method attribute to verify if the passed request is valid for each of the action methods.

This is the attribute class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class ParameterValueMatchAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
   public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
   {
      var value = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request[Name];
      return (value == Value);
   }

   public string Value { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I have each one of the action methods with the same name and decorated like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[ParameterValueMatch(Name="Step", Value="1")]
public ActionResult Create(Model01 model)
```

I like this approach a LOT more than creating one route for each method.